# Ordered enumeration

Tags: c#, containers, enumeration

Several collections available in .NET standard libraries are designed to keep an order of items held inside - such as `List`, `LinkedList`, `Queue` or `Stack`. Others, on the other hand, arrange items in other way, such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

My question is: If a container keeps elements in specific order (in sequence), **is it guaranteed**, that enumerating through this container will initially be done in that order?

For instance, I want to enumerate through items of the list in reverse order. The simple way is to write:

```
foreach (var item in list.Reverse<type>()) { ... }
```

But that will work only if initial enumerator goes through items of the collection in order in which they are stored inside. If there's no such guarantee, I should probably write the code in other way:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

Which actually is shorter, but surely less readable.

*Note*: I know, that list actually enumerates the items in order and intuition says, that all ordered containers will do the same. But if it is not guaranteed by the framework, .NET 5.0 may introduce enumerating in (for instance) more efficient way, but breaking order of items.

---

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwyysy67(v=vs.110).aspx) *suggests*, that the order is kept by using terms like "Before first element in the collection" and "Move to the next element in the collection". But is it enough to say, that the order is **guaranteed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that anyone (even Microsoft) can guarantee how future software will behave. However, the MSDN page you link to says, "for example, an enumerator for an ArrayList preserves the order in which the elements are entered in the collection." `List<T>` is an ordered list and I would say an enumerator that returned the items out of order is broken. I think you can safely use `Reverse<T>`. Keep in mind that any changes to the List will invalidate your enumerator. Make sure your list isn't altered by any other threads while you are enumerating it.